# How can you detect when a player hits a block in Adventure Mode [version 1.16.5] in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft, I am trying to make a map in Adventure Mode where you sell/buy trees. I want to be able to detect whenever a player has punched an oak log in Adventure Mode, and then it would automatically break the log. How would I go about doing this? I don't want to use any data packs/plugins.

Comment: Why don't you want to use data packs? They're the primary method for creating command machines. Command blocks are more of a secondary method nowadays.

Comment: You could give the player an axe with the nbt `CanDestroy` with the value of whatever block they should break.